Make host-commandos available in venv
I am trying to call/run some commands from the linux host (like git-lfs and tree).
Obviously I get commando not available inside the venv.
Is there any way to make these commandos available within the venv?

I cannot reproduce your issue, for me tree works as a charm within venvs. Afaik venvs should redirect to system packages for anything not in the venv itself?
